# GIMP 2.7.5 crashed theme and applications

Tags: 11.10, software-sources, downgrade, gimp, partial-upgrade

I am using Ubuntu 11.10. I was using GIMP 2.6 from the repo but I read that GIMP 2.7 has merged windows, I wish I hadn't but I wondered it and added the following PPA: **matthaeus123/mrw-gimp-svn**

After that it required me to add two other repos:

*GIMP 2.7.5 Will not work with the current glib and gtk in Oneiric. To fix the problem install these repos*

deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome3-team/gnome3/ubuntu oneiric main

deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ricotz/testing/ubuntu oneiric main

I added those PPAs and in somewhere a pop-up with "partial-update" appeared I applied the update and restarted Ubuntu. After the restart, my theme was a little bit changed, when I right-click the color is not gray but white and most importantly I am not able to reach:

- **Software Sources**, when clicked it looks as if opening and then closes.
- *sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list* doesn't work, because my Gedit doesn't work.
- **Preferences** in **Nautilus**, when clicked it closes Nautilus.

I would like to revert everything I updated. I would like to downgrade/remove the packages **ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3** and **ppa:ricotz/testing** PPAs but I am unable to do it.

So, I am stuck. How do I restore everything?

Comment: run "sudo apt-get -f install" might straighten out the partial update

Comment: Thanks for answer @BlueXrider, but nothing changed. Everything is same.

Comment: Gimp 2.7.5 introduces new plugins which requires new libraries which in turn require a newer version of Gnome, that's why it's all messed up, for me and apparently for you Themes in newer versions of Gnome are broken.

Comment: Only way without re-installing is, get yourself another DE, completely remove *everything* Gnome, and re install the version in the repos.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what happened, new libraries messed everything up. I was able to remove GIMP 2.7 and now GIMP 2.6 works; however, my Themes are broken, and most importantly **Software Sources** is unavailable both from Software Centre and from terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution!

As @solomenikmi said, I applied these commands:

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge    

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3    
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ricotz/testing
```

However, it did not solve the problem related to Themes and applications. So, I started searching and while searching I [found a solution](http://supportlife.wordpress.com/2011/05/31/tutorial-how-to-removeuninstall-gnome-3-in-ubuntu-11-04-natty-narwhal/) and applied the following:

```
sudo apt-get remove libgtk-3-common
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install gnome-panel
sudo reboot
```

It seemed as if everything worked well; however, that solution was proposed for **Ubuntu 11.04** but I am using **Ubuntu 11.10** and it messed up the system again! This time, I was not even able to reach to login screen of Ubuntu, after I press the power button of my laptop, the start-up was freezing at **Checking battery state... [ OK ]**. After searching again, I applied those following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install lightdm-gtk-greeter
sudo apt-get install unity-greeter
sudo reboot
```

And that was it. I succeeded to return to the state where my themes and applications work just like before installing GIMP 2.7.5!

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge    

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3    
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ricotz/testing
```

*without previous two commands I had problems with "ppa-purge"

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade    
sudo ppa-purge ppa:ricotz/testing    
sudo ppa-purge ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
```

reboot

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I found that solution somewhere and tried, but did not work. I mean, the packages were removed but my Theme and applications still don't work. So, still searching...